# postgis error in compiling on mac os x snow leopard

Tags: macos, postgresql, compilation, postgis

I'm trying to compile postgis 1.5.2 on Mac OS X and running Postgresql 8.4 (installed via one click installer from enterprisedb).

I've used kyngchaos's GDAL complete binary package for postgis and added this to my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/UnixImageIO.framework/Programs:$PATH
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Programs:$PATH
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Programs:$PATH
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Programs:$PATH
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
```

I've downloaded the current postgis source and ran ./configure it stops at the end with:

```
checking PostgreSQL version... PostgreSQL 8.4.3
checking libpq-fe.h usability... yes
checking libpq-fe.h presence... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PQserverVersion in -lpq... no
configure: error: could not find libpq
```

Thus not making the postgis_config.h file for make.

Comment: Have you tried to install Postgis thru the StackBuilder (which is part of the one-click installer, at least on Windows)?

Comment: Well enterprisedb's install doesn't have that option when I installed it a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Check the configure.log. It can be some error related with libpq or some library that libpq needs.